# Dropbear - Build only scp

Tags: ssh, scp, dropbear

We are using dropbear to perform the scp and ssh functionalities. The security department is concerned about the ssh client in the production builds.  But, we need scp functionality to transfer the files in the production images. How can I disable dropbear's ssh without disabling scp functionality?

Comment: I am not sure about dropbear implementation, but `scp` is using `ssh` internally, so the thing you want to achieve is probably impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropbear is a lightweight replaced of openssh in the embedded systems. It provides the following functionalities:

> dbclient  dropbearkey  dropbearconvert scp ssh

It also provides an option in the makefile to build only scp utility. Production images needs to build and include only scp binary whereas the debug images should build and include all the dropbear binaries.

```
$(MAKE) PROGRAMS="scp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that "SCP" is dependent upon dbclient, so you need to build that also.

```
$make PROGRAMS="scp dbclient"
```